# Incorrect 'You have already raised this type of flag' notice

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, close-reasons

I just voted to close [What language(s) would animals speak?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11328/what-languages-would-animals-speak) as 'too broad'. When I again clicked on *flag* there are suddenly **two** 'already used' notifications:

[image]

Is this a bug?

*Sorry for not drawing [free hand ellipses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/189029)*

Answer (score 4):

When you don't have the reputation needed to cast actual close votes, what you're actually doing is flagging to *suggest* closure. Once you've flagged *for closure*, the other options that suggest reasons why the question should be closed aren't available, as you've already flagged that the question should be closed.

Notice the others are still there, e.g. quality related, spam, other. This is very similar to how you can't cast 2 close votes on a single question.

If you make a mistake in the reason for closure that you picked, just use 'other' and leave a note to the moderator that you actually meant to use another.

Comment: That last of course being conditioned on *if the error requires moderator intervention*. We don't have a lot of flags on Worldbuilding, and even fewer moderator-only flags, but anything to keep the number of diamond-moderator-only flags down is still welcome. :)